# Doing arithmetic operation on android shell

Tags: android, shell

I am banging my head on the wall trying to do a floating point arithmetic operations on Android. Doing so much research forced me to use sqlite3 to get my floating point calculation done.

```
sqlite3 <<< "SELECT 16.8/1.2"
```

Unfortunately, I am restricted to not use sqlite3 in my script. I tried most of the things but I don't have `bc` or `awk` on my device as well.

**EDIT**: I have to run a shell script on the android phone for an embedded project. Basically, I am working with decimal point temperature values read on the phone and I need to do an arithmetic operation on that.

Can anyone give me a quick pointer here?

**Note: My device is not rooted.**

Comment: Please edit your question to add detail as do what you are doing, as 'bash' isn't a default Android app, and as written I can't tell what the end goal is even if you are using a terminal/shell app.

Comment: Is this busybox, or is this literally the binaries that ship with Android?

Comment: Binaries that ships with android.

Comment: How about doing fixed point calculations instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the "bc" command in termux.
If you want to use it in an app, it may be possible to get the executable binary and use it as a resource.

You will also need to use sh to execute the script on command line as
$sh script.sh. Any binaries would have to be put as resources of an app in order to be executable.